# js findIndex function beginner level

Tags: javascript

Im going through a tutorial and to get used to the findIndexFunction in Javascript, we had to create this function.

```
function findIndex(arr, callback) {
    for ( var i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){ 
        if callback(arr[i],i,arr){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

so what i dont understand is how does the program know that callback in the first line is a function and not just an ordinary parameter because later in line 3 it has become a function. 
Also i believe this exercise is for us to create a findIndex function or could it be that the first line already implements a findIndex function, if so why would the term function be stated. If this was the findIndex Function wouldnt  findIndex(arr, callback) {} instead of function findIndex(arr, callback) {} be enough ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

> so what i dont understand is how does the program know that callback in the first line is a function and not just an ordinary parameter

Functions are first class objects in JS. They can be passed about like any other value. It **is** an "ordinary parameter".

Your code tries to treat the parameter as a function. If it is one, all is good. If it isn't one, then the person who wrote the code which calls findIndex made a mistake and it will error.

> wouldnt findIndex(arr, callback) {} instead of function findIndex(arr, callback) {} be enough

No. That simply isn't the syntax used for declaring a function in JS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regardeing ->No. That simply isn't the syntax used for declaring a function in JS.  But findIndex is a predefined method in javascript, so therefor i thaught i could be possible to be called without function. Whats your take on this ?

Comment: @SamsonKemba — Your question is about creating your own version of `findIndex`, not calling the existing one!